# how to fix veins error "attempt to read past end of byte buffer-- in module(veins::MyveinsAPP "

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

[veins error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t70XZ.png)
I want to get last step vhicle number of one lane. So i have build a function by "LAST_STEP_VEHICLE_NUMBER" in TraCIConstants.h. The function is shown in Figure 2.[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqgN4.png)
When the function was invoked ,the error come.
How to solve the problem above?

Answer (score 0):

The number of vehicles is an integer so you should probably use genericGetInt (and return an int) instead of double.